# Getting error while using LUIS recognizer

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

Whenever I'm trying to get response using below code, I'm getting exception 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).'. Please help me out.

var luisApp = new LuisApplication(configuration["LuisAppId"], configuration["LuisAPIKey"], configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]);
var recognizerResult = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

Comment: Have you provided values for all three of those properties in your configuration?

Comment: Is Yutong's answer acceptable?

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about LUIS recognizer class, I will highly suggest you check properties and anything else according to the document:

PROPERTIES
applicationId
Your models application Id from LUIS

endpoint
(Optional) LUIS endpoint with a default of https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

endpointKey
Endpoint key for talking to LUIS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-ai/luisapplication?view=botbuilder-ts-latest

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I forgot to apply (while developing the solution), was that the LUIS application has to be deployment to the **production slot** as well.  If that does not happen, you'll get that 404 as well.  Just wanted to share, in case others need it.